# SharePoint App Store Says This Page Can't be Displayed

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have just installed the Yammer and World Clock apps in SharePoint 2013 in a dev server.
 When i click on the app from site contents, it shows "this page can't be displayed" and in the app part it says "internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Initially thought it is the problem with Yammer App and used the solutions provided in: (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx) but it is the same for the other Apps.